# Font Helvetica for math in headings

Tags: sectioning

Here is a simple Latex code. The main text is Times Roman, bat the fonts in headings is Helvetica.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% Times Roman font
\usepackage{helvet}% Helvetica, served as a model for arial
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{blue}}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{cyan}}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The firs chapter $x=y^2$}
 \lipsum[1]
 
\section{Differentiating the exponential function $y=e^x$}
 \lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}
```

Here is PDF output.

[image]

I would like to get the math equations in the chapter and section headings in Helvetica font.

If someone knows the solution, I ask for help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Some suggestions, to be implemented jointly:

- Load the `sansmath` package
- Instead of the loading obsolescent `mathptmx` package, consider loading the newer `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages. A side benefit of this change is that the `helvet` font will automatically be made the default sans-serif font, properly scaled no less. Thus, no need to load the `helvet` package. (Many thanks to @campa for pointing out that the `newtxtext` package automatically loads an Helvetica clone!)
- Insert the directive `\boldmath` in the second main argument of `titleformat`.
- Encase any and all math-mode material in the chapter and section headers in `\mathsf` wrappers.

Incidentally, this method works satisfactorily only with very simple formulas (as as the ones you provided). Don't expect good results if the formulas in question involve fractions, summation symbols, integral symbols, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,sansmath}
%%\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{helvet} % no need to load if "newtxtext" package is loaded
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries\color{blue}\boldmath}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries\color{cyan}\boldmath}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter: $\mathsf{x=y^2}$}

\section{Differentiating the exponential function $\mathsf{y=e^x}$}

Text mode: $x=y^2$, $y=e^x$
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, `newtxtext` already loads the  Helvetica clone TeX Gyre Heros as sans-serif font. And it's already correctly scaled. Further global scaling of both or of `tgheros` alone are possible through package options. But +1 anyway `:-)`

Comment: @campa - Many thanks for this comment. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: the solution would only produce some arbitrary sans-serif font. Even 2 in your screenshot is not rendered using helvetica